# Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-jest

This error is coming up when I am making a pull request. There is a GitHub workflow audit that runs checks on the pull request and it loads the test file from another repository.

```
- name: Run Audits
      run: npx jest audits/ch-2 --json --outputFile=audits/ch-2.json --noStackTrace


Test suite failed to run

    /Users/frankukachukwu/StudioProjects/covid-19-estimator-tksilicon-js/babel.config.js: Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Don't you have a `jest.config.js` ?

Comment: Even more with nodejs I am surprised that you need babel

Comment: No Julien, please what should I do?

Comment: do you use `import` or `require` ?

Comment: I had to support ES6 styled code like export default and import instead of require and module.exports because it a predetermined style which must be met to pass PR checks. @JulienTASSIN

Comment: @tksilicon you need to provide the solution as an 'answer', not nested in your question. Please can you fix?

Comment: @Gaz_Edge fixed.

Comment: Try removing `"type": "module"` from `package.json` file

Answer (score 169, accepted):

TL;DR: Changing `babel.config.<extension>` to `babel.config.cjs` did the work. Check [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files) if you need a different config.

This has got to do with Babel settings. The use of .mjs, cjs or .js extension for the babel.config.extension. In my case where I was running LTE Node 12.6.2. I needed this configuration at the root of my directory babel.config.cjs. cjs is what is applicable for Nodejs when using "type"="module". See more about it [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files) on babel docs.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

And jest.config.cjs at the root too.

Comment: Renaming babel.config.js to babel.config.cjs did it for me! Thanks.

Comment: @pbatey wow how do you explain that ?! Anyway thanks buddy saved me time.

Comment: @Amesys I read that cjs means commonJS, I've been using node with --experimental-modules so I'm guessing .js defaults to modules (import) instead of commonJS (require).

Answer (score 43):

In addition to "cjs" solution, I was able to resolve this issue by converting `babel.config.js` to `babel.config.json`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

Comment: this works as well, please note that `@babel/preset-typescript` needs to be installed

Comment: This helped me resolve the issue on my end, with vite.

Comment: For me only this solution worked and I also had to add to `package.json` this jest config:
`"jest": { "modulePaths": ["<rootDir>"] }`