# Jest not running tests - Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm having a problem configuring Jest to run my tests. When running `npm test -- --watchAll --no-cache` I get the message

> babel.config.js: Error while loading config - You appear to be using a
> native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported
> when running Babel asynchronously.

I've already checked other issues here on the OS, notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146112/error-while-loading-config-you-appear-to-be-using-a-native-ecmascript-module-c), but when I change the extension from babel.config to `.cjs`, the following message appears

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is
> not configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
>
> Details:
>
> SyntaxError: <project_root>/src/filmes/gerenciador.js:
> Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (13:24)

Below is my configuration files

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myfilms",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
        "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
        "jest": "^27.0.6",
        "json-server": "^0.16.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
    }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    node: "current",
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

Jest's and Babel's documentation is pretty confusing about these cases, and each of the solutions I try alternates between these two types of errors. Is there any standard way to configure Jest to support `imports/exports` and `await/async`?