# Jest - Test an ES6 class

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm learning to test my JavaScript with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started). I have a basic project that's setup like this:

```
/
  /src
    myClass.js
  /tests
    myClass.test.js
  package.json
```

The code looks like this:

**myClass.js**

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.result = null;
  }

  calculate() {
    this.result = 1;
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

**myClass.test.js**

```
import { MyClass } from '../src/myClass';

test('Calculate', () => {
  let myObject = new MyClass();
  let result = myObject.calculate();
  expect(result).toBe(1);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "sample-project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "type":"module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "serve": "vite preview",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.2.16",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.9.3",
        "jest": "^27.3.1",
        "vite": "^2.6.4",
        "vite-plugin-html": "^2.1.1",
        "vite-plugin-singlefile": "^0.5.1"
    }
}
```

When I run my tests using `npm run test`, which just executes `jest`, I receive an error that says: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I test `MyClass` from Jest?

Comment: [Is your project set up as `"type": "module"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655153)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `../src/MyClass` anyway?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are correct. I miscopied it over. The reference is correct. I will update the question.

Comment: @VLAZ My project is setup as "type":"module"

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file, too?

Comment: @BadPiggie unfortunately, no. I'm not using TypeScript, Babel, or Webpack. I'm using good ol' fashioned JavaScript.

Comment: @VLAZ I just added the `package.json` code.

Comment: OK I reproduced this locally. Which is your version of Node.js?

Comment: @VLAZ I have v12.18.2 of Node running locally.

Comment: Ooh, I don't think that would work. Node [started supporting modules in 13.2.0](https://nodejs.medium.com/announcing-core-node-js-support-for-ecmascript-modules-c5d6dc29b663) as an experimental feature. 14.0.0 was the first LTS with module support. You might need to update your Node installation or use babel or something to use this with 12.18.2, I think.

Comment: @VLAZ I just updated my Node.js installation to version v14.18.1. I also deleted my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file. I then ran `npm install`. When I tried to run my test via Jest, via `npm run test`, I still experienced the same issue.

Comment: Ugh, so turns out that Jest itself also doesn't fully support modules. I'm trying to wrangle it to work with minimal effort. EDIT: I did get it to work in 14.1.0 with `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest` but it's a bit ugly. Supposedly there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the `Babel` sections in the [Jest's Getting Started Guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/getting-started#using-babel)

Simply run:

```
yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

and create a `babel.config.js` file in the project root directory with the following content:

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}]],
};
```

FYI:
Jest is using virtual Node environments under the hood. If I remember correctly the oldest supported Node version is 10. Therefore you need to configure a source code transformer like Babel if you want to use ES6 features. ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YDiloj8_d0&ab_channel=ChristophNakazawa))

Comment: I added `babel.config.js` to the root (i.e. `/`) directory of my project. When I run `npm run test`, I receive an error that says: `babel.config.js: Error while loading config - You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.`

Comment: I think this could be caused by your Node version!? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146112/error-while-loading-config-you-appear-to-be-using-a-native-ecmascript-module-c

Comment: Maybe renaming it to `babel.config.cjs` works!?

Comment: that worked! Thanks!