Testing in React Native with ts: Cannot use import statement outside a module
When running my test using Jest in my React-Native project with typescript, I cant manage to get rid of this import error:
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
I only have a render in the test I wish to run:
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import { Feed } from "./Feed";

describe("Feed", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("renders correctly", async () => {
    /////////////////////
    ////// ARRANGE //////
    /////////////////////

    /////////////////////
    //////   ACT   //////
    /////////////////////
    render(<Feed />);

    ////////////////////
    ////// ASSERT //////
    ////////////////////
  });
});

The error is at line 2.
Here is my packege.json file :
{
  "name": "expo-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/html-elements": "latest",
    "@gluestack-style/legend-motion-animation-driver": "^1.0.3",
    "@gluestack-style/react": "latest",
    "@gluestack-ui/config": "latest",
    "@gluestack-ui/themed": "^1.0.37",
    "@legendapp/motion": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "@react-spring/native": "^9.5.5",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.5.5",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "expo": "~48.0.17",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.73.2",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.1",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index-module.js",
    "require": "./index-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
}

My babel.config.js file :
export default function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      "babel-preset-expo",
      ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ],
  };
}

My tsconfig.json file :
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ES2022"
  }
}

And finaly my jest.config.js file:
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
};

I tried changing my config files, like suggested in other threads, and I installed ts-jest but I had no success in solving my issue.
Here is a screenshot of my latest error after I tried several workarounds.


You will need to use
"type": "module"

in your package.json.
Example:
// package.json
{
  "exports": {
    "import": "./index-module.js",
    "require": "./index-require.cjs"
  },
  "type": "module"
} 

Also, look at https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-module-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope
Your code of
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      "@babel/preset-react",
    ],
  };
};

is also erroring out. Try refactoring the syntax in the manner the link describes, i.e., the syntax of export ....

Hi !
I tried this solution but it brings up a ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope

@AngelRafael that's good news, because it means you solved your first problem and now you are facing the second one. See this link: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-module-is-not-defined-in-es-module-scope

@AngelRafael I have edited my answer to provide you more information.

Thank you for the help! I followed your instructions and looked at the documentation, but I still have te same error. I will maby migrate the project from typescript to javascript.

@AngelRafael can you edit your question and show your current try?

I updated my question following your advice, I changed my package.json an my babel.config.js. I am also getting this error now : You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously.

@AngelRafael is this link helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146112/error-while-loading-config-you-appear-to-be-using-a-native-ecmascript-module-c

I just tried and now I have import error within my node_modules. A deleted tham and reinstalled. Issue is still present unfortunately, I added a screenshot to my post.
